# Randomize 2 fields in Loop and Merge Qualtrics (Parallel Loop)

Tags: loops, random, qualtrics

I'm trying to do a survey in Qualtrics, and there is something that would be really handy that I can not achieve to do: 
In the Loop and merge, I would like that all fields are randomized independently of each others: 
 If I have this "Loop and merge":

```
       Field 1     Field 2 
 1.       A           One
 2.       B           Two
```

I would like to be able to get all 4 possibilities: "A-One", "B-Two", "A-Two", "B-One".

My real problem is that I'm presenting two pictures simultaneously, and I would like that one particular picture is only getting presented once. If I do four loops, with the four possibilities, and pick two, I might get twice the same item, so this would not suit my study.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Store the pictures in embedded variables and randomize them in a randomizer block.

```
aPic = One
bPic = Two

or 

aPic = Two
bPic = One
```

Then your loop is:

```
     Field1     Field2
1.     A        ${e://Field/aPic}
2.     B        ${e://Field/bPic}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried several things out with the embedded variables. But I don't only have 2 pictures, but 30, which makes it difficult to define embedded variables for all possible order combinations.

Comment: For complex randomization, your best option is to assign embedded variables using a web service script.